# When the user hovers over any li I want to show the ::after pseudo element of the li with the class of .menu__item--current

Tags: html, css, animation, dom

Here's my `HTML`. All I'm trying to do is animate some hover effects on the `li`'s.

```
<section class="section section--menu" id="big_menu">
  <h2 class="section__title">Big Menu</h2>
  <span class="link-copy"></span>
  <nav class="menu menu--big_menu">
    <ul class="menu__list">
      <li class="menu__item menu__item--current"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Clients</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Shop</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

The `li` with the class of `.menu__item--current` represents the current page/link and has red text.

When the user hovers over any of the other `li`'s with class `.menu_item` the `::before` pseudo element appears. When that happens I also want the `li.menu__item--current`'s `::after` pseudo element to appear.

It needs to happen regardless of where the `li.menu__item--current` is in the `ul` order.

I only want to use `CSS` for this!

Here's my current (relevant) `CSS`

```
/* Big Menu */

/* spacing & alignment */
.menu--big_menu li {
    margin: 1em 1em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

/* color */
.menu--big_menu .menu__list .menu__item--current .menu__link,
.menu--big_menu .menu__link:hover,
.menu--big_menu .menu__link:focus {
    color: #d94f5c;
}

/* pseudo elements */
.menu--big_menu .menu__item::before,
.menu--big_menu .menu__item::after {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: #D94F5C;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 9px 4px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .6s ease;
  transition: all .6s ease;
}

.menu--big_menu .menu__list .menu__item:hover::before {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 5px;
    height: 21px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.menu--big_menu .menu__item::before {
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -3px;
}

.menu--big_menu .menu__item::after {
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -3px;
}

/* if .menu__item--current:hover dont show pseudo elements */
.menu--big_menu .menu__list .menu__item--current:hover::before,
.menu--big_menu .menu__list .menu__item--current:hover::after,
.menu--big_menu .menu__list .menu__item--current:focus::before,
.menu--big_menu .menu__list .menu__item--current:focus::after {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* if .menu__item:hover show .menu__item--current::after */



/* End: Big Menu */
```

You'll notice there's no code below the comment where I want to make this happen. That's because I have tried lots of different methods and none worked, so for now it's just empty. You should try fill it `:)`

Also this is obviously not the complete `css` as there are clearly more styles needed to properly display the page. But this is the only section we need to worry about here. And yes all other styles are written above this section in the stylesheet.

[Here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paralellos/4tmpk1yb/#&togetherjs=MRP5PzAaFK)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I haven't seen any li.menu__item--current ::after pseudo css styling  in your codes..So I will be deleting my answer until this piece of information is provided....good luck